# Undefined index vimeo

Tags: php, vimeo

Im using a function to get vimeo data, but its throwing out a the following notice:

Notice: Undefined index: url in /Users/admin/Dropbox/Sites/wordpressSkeletonFog/wp-content/themes/skeleton/page-watch.php on line 117

Line 117 in my code block refers to code below 
// Get the video url from the url, or use default

Any Ideas? Many thanks

```
 <?php
        function curl_get($url) { 
            // is cURL installed? If not die
            if (!function_exists('curl_init')) die('cURL is not installed!');

            // Create new cURL resource handle
            $curl = curl_init($url);

            //Return or print out the data (1 = return, 0 = print)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


        //Set Timeout in Seconds
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);


        //Download the URL, and return the output
            $output = curl_exec($curl);

            // Close the cURL resources     
            curl_close($curl);
            return

        $output;
            }
        // Hard-coded endpoint
        $oembed_endpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed';
        // The Vimeo video to be embedded
        $id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_video_embed' , true);
        // Get the video url from the url, or use default
        $video_url = ($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'http://vimeo.com/' . $id;
        // Create the url
        $xml_url = $oembed_endpoint . '.xml?url=' . rawurlencode($video_url) . '&width=640';
        // Load in the oEmbed XML
        $oembed = simplexml_load_string(curl_get($xml_url));
        ?>
        <?php
        // oEmbed Result
        echo html_entity_decode($oembed->html); 
        ?>
        <?php
        echo $oembed->title 
        ?>
        <?php
        echo $oembed->author_name 
        ?>
        <?php
        echo $oembed->description 
        ?>
        <?php  endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are getting  Undefined index 'Upload-Offset' then change 'Upload-Offset' to 'upload-offset' at all places in Vimeo.php file and the error get's fixed.

It's also given in [github issue](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/issues/232)

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
$video_url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'http://vimeo.com/' . $id;
```

Instead of

```
$video_url = ($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'http://vimeo.com/' . $id;
```

First you need to check `url` exists in `$_GET`. `isset` function will it.